# Allow mixed state but not on click with NSButton (checkbox)

Tags: swift, macos, checkbox, subclass, nsbutton

I have a checkbox (`NSButton`) that I set programmatically. This checkbox will be set to other `on`, `off` or `mixed`, but when the user clicks it I want it to *only cycle* between `on` and `off`.

Currently, when `button.allowsMixedState = true` when the user clicks on the checkbox it will cycle between all three states.

Is there a way to have `button.allowsMixedState = true` but only have the checkbox cycle between `on` and `off` when it's clicked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to finally get this working, by subclassing the `NSButtonCell` rather than the `NSButton` and overriding its `nextState` property:

(This example was run with Swift 4)

```
// 0 is .off, 1 is .on and -1 is .mixed.
// We override nextState so that it can never be -1.
class MyButtonCell: NSButtonCell {
    override var nextState: Int {
        get {
            return self.state == .on ? 0 : 1
        }
    }
}
```

This means I can set the checkbox's state to `mixed`, but when the user clicks it the checkbox will only cycle between `on` or `off`.

Comment: There **has** to be a solution that does not involve subclassing...?